# Swift bridging 2D Array to type UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>?>?

Tags: swift, pointers, pointer-to-pointer, c-api

Hi I am trying to wrap a C api using Swift 4

Swift has imported a function with the following signature.

`public typealias indicator = @convention(c) (Int32, UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Double>?>?, UnsafePointer<Double>?, UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>?>?) -> Int32`

according to the C libraries docs then the signature is as follows:

`int indicator(int size,
             double const *const *inputs,
             double const *options,
             double *const *outputs);`

It’s worth noting that the `int` return from the function is in c style the error type of the function, the actual return is in the `outputs` pointer

So then assuming I create the following Swift types

`let inputs: [[Double]] = []
    let options: [Double] = []
    var outputs: [[Double]] = []`

with some appropriate values then I should be able to do something like: ( note `info.pointee.indicator` is the imported function )

```
internal func calculateIndicator(options opts: [Double], input inputs: [[Double]], output outPuts: inout [[Double]]) -> [[Double]]? {
    guard let sz = inputs.first?.count else {fatalError("Must supply a [[Double]] input param")}

    let inputPointer = UnsafePointer<[Double]>(inputs)
    let optionsPointer = UnsafePointer<Double>(opts)
    var outputPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<[Double]>(&outPuts)

    let val = info.pointee.indicator(Int32(sz), inputPointer, optionsPointer, outputPointer)

    // do something with the outputs and return the values
}
```

however the compiler complains with the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'indicator' with an argument list of type '(Int32, UnsafePointer<[Double]>, UnsafePointer<Double>, UnsafeMutablePointer<[Double]>)'
```

This sort of makes sense as I am passing the incorrect types ( I think ).

So then memory management issues aside how would I go about converting the `[[Double]]` types to for example the `UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>>` pointer?

according to the docs here [Calling Functions With Pointer Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management/calling_functions_with_pointer_parameters) I should be able to do this with implicit bridging but it seems not, perhaps I should just create the pointer types rather than try and convert from Swift?

Thanks in advance, I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

The C API itself is as follows:

```
typedef int (*indicator_function)(int size,
  double const *const *inputs,
  double const *options,
  double *const *outputs);

typedef struct indicator_info {
  char *name;
  char *full_name;
  indicator_start_function start;
  indicator_function indicator;
  int type, inputs, options, outputs;
  char *input_names[MAXINDPARAMS];
  char *option_names[MAXINDPARAMS];
  char *output_names[MAXINDPARAMS];
} indicator_info;
```

The `indicator` function is accessed through the struct above.

A given instance of an indicator function is as follows

```
int add(int size,
  TI_REAL const *const *inputs,
  TI_REAL const *options,
  TI_REAL *const *outputs);
```

Comment: “Swift has imported a function with the following signature” No. According to that, `indicator` is not a function that you call. It is a type (signature) of a function that you pass. Show the C API where we actually have to pass it.

Comment: well it is a type alias to a whole bunch of functions that all have the following signature `public func indicator_abs(_ size: Int32, _ inputs: UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Double>?>!, _ options: UnsafePointer<Double>!, _ outputs: UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>?>!) -> Int32`. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

the problem here lies in the fact that the C API requires these parameters `double *const *outputs` and `double const *const *inputs` or in Swift terms `[[Double]]` types.

This `C` function signature is imported by Swift into the following types respectively.

```
UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>?> 
UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Double>?>
```

Whilst easy to bridge from `[T]` to `UnsafePointer<T>` it's not so easy to go to the bulky `UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<T>>` and `UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<T>>`. Nor is there any documentation that I can find related to these conversions.

I did find an excellent blog post regarding pointers to `UInt8` arrays by Ole Begemann which got me most of the way there, the blog is [Passing an Array of Strings from Swift to C](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/10/swift-array-of-c-strings/).

In this he creates a `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` pointer to a `[String]` type and then rebinds the memory, as can be seen below and then goes on to use the offsets of the `CChar` arrays,  you can read about this in the above referenced article

```
public func withArrayOfCStrings<R>(
   _ args: [String],
   _ body: ([UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?]) -> R) -> R {
      let argsCounts = Array(args.map { $0.utf8.count + 1 })
      let argsOffsets = [ 0 ] + scan(argsCounts, 0, +)
      let argsBufferSize = argsOffsets.last!

      var argsBuffer: [UInt8] = []
      argsBuffer.reserveCapacity(argsBufferSize)
      for arg in args {
          argsBuffer.append(contentsOf: arg.utf8)
          argsBuffer.append(0)
      }

     return argsBuffer.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (argsBuffer) in
         let ptr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(argsBuffer.baseAddress!).bindMemory(
         to: CChar.self, capacity: argsBuffer.count)
         var cStrings: [UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?] = argsOffsets.map { ptr + $0 }
         cStrings[cStrings.count - 1] = nil
         return body(cStrings)
     }
}
```

As escaping bridged pointers is undefined behaviour according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer) it is necessary to do the bridging and calling inside a closure as Ole Bergmann suggests in his article.

To accomplish this we create a similar function:

```
func indicatorWithArrays<R>(inputs ins:[[Double]],
                            options opts: [Double],
                            outputs out: [[Double]],
                            ti body: ([UnsafePointer<Double>?], 
                                      UnsafePointer<Double>?, 
                                      [UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>?]) -> R) -> R
```

this is generic over type `R` its Return type as before.

Inside the function we bridge the inputs and outputs into `UnsafeBufferPointer`'s and then call `map` on the resultant buffers to create a variable of type `[UnsafePointer<Double>]` which can then be passed to the closure body.

```
return ins.withUnsafeBufferPointer { (inputsBuffer) in
    var inPuts: [UnsafePointer<Double>?] = inputsBuffer.map { UnsafePointer($0) }                                      
    return out.withUnsafeBufferPointer { (outputsBuffer) in
            var outPtrPtr: [UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>?] 
                = outputBuffer.map { UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: $0) }                 
            return body(inPuts, opts, outPtrPtr)
        }
    }
```

The passing of the `[UnsafePointer<Double>]` param to the `body` closure implicitly bridges to the required `UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Double>>` and the `UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>>` required by the imported C API.

The `indicatorWithArrays` function is called as follows and allows us to then use the bridged pointers in the imported C function:

```
return indicatorWithArrays(inputs: input, options: opts, outputs: resArray) { (input, opts, outputs) in
            let sz = inputs?.first?.count ?? 0
            switch TIReturnType(rawValue: tulipInfo.info.pointee.indicator(Int32(sz), input, opts, outputs)) {
            case .ti_okay?:
                for (index, item) in outputs.enumerated() {
                    let buff = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: item, count: resArray[index].count)
                    resArray[index] = Array(buff)
                }
                return resArray
            case nil:
                return nil
            }
        }
```

where the call is: `tulipInfo.info.pointee.indicator(Int32(sz), input, opts, outputs)`

The *Magic* is all about the passing closures between the functions and thereby ensuring that we don't escape the bridged  pointers, Ole Bergmann's solution is fine for `String` types but hopefully this helps someone else who is stuck with type `[[T]]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have, as you state in your comment, a C function that Swift has typed like this:

```
public func indicator_abs(_ size: Int32, 
    _ inputs: UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Double>?>!, 
    _ options: UnsafePointer<Double>!, 
    _ outputs: UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>?>!) -> Int32
```

...then I think you can call it as follows:

```
    let inputs = [1.0, 2.0]
    let options = [1.0, 1.0]
    var outputs = [0.0, 0.0]

    let result:Int32 = withUnsafePointer(to: inputs) { inputsPtr in
        withUnsafePointer(to: &outputs) { outputsPtr in
            indicator_abs(2,inputsPtr,options,outputsPtr)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but there are a couple of things, the parameters `inputs` and `outputs` are of type `[[Double]]` and also in C style `result` is the error type of the function the actual output needed in in `outputs`. So I don’t think this would work as I dont think we can escape the `outputsPtr`