# How to pass [[Int]] into MTLBuffer in Swift and receive it in Metal?

Tags: c++, swift, metal

## What I'm trying to do

I have an `[[Int]]` in Swift and I'm trying to pass it into Metal through a buffer. Basically, I'm trying to use Metal to add two matrices multithreaded and give them back to Swift. So far, this is more difficult than expected.

## The problem

Metal tells me that my graph isn't a pointer and I suspect I'm passing it into Metal wrong.

```swift
import MetalKit

let graph: [[Int]] = [
    [0, 1, 2, 999, 999, 999],
    [1, 0, 999, 5, 1, 999],
    [2, 999, 0, 2, 3, 999],
    [999, 5, 2, 0, 2, 2],
    [999, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1],
    [999, 999, 999, 2, 1, 0]]

func fooFunc(gra: [[Int]]) {
    
    let count = gra.count

    let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()

    let commandQueue = device?.makeCommandQueue()

    let gpuFunctionLibrary = device?.makeDefaultLibrary()

    let funcGPUFunction = gpuFunctionLibrary?.makeFunction(name: "MetalFunc")

    var funcPipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState!
    do {
        funcPipelineState = try device?.makeComputePipelineState(function: funcGPUFunction!)
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }

    let graphBuff = device?.makeBuffer(bytes: gra,
                                      length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size * count * count,
                                      options: .storageModeShared)
    let resultBuff = device?.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size * count,
                                        options: .storageModeShared)

    let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()

    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
    commandEncoder?.setComputePipelineState(additionComputePipelineState)

    commandEncoder?.setBuffer(graphBuff, offset: 0, index: 0)
    commandEncoder?.setBuffer(resultBuff, offset: 0, index: 1)

    let threadsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: count, height: 1, depth: 1)
    let maxThreadsPerThreadgroup = additionComputePipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup // 1024
    let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: maxThreadsPerThreadgroup, height: 1, depth: 1)
    commandEncoder?.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid,
                                    threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)

    commandEncoder?.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer?.commit()
    commandBuffer?.waitUntilCompleted()
    
    let resultBufferPointer = resultBuff?.contents().bindMemory(to: Int.self,
                                                                capacity: MemoryLayout<Int>.size * count)

    print("Result: \(Int(resultBufferPointer!.pointee) as Any)")
}


gpuDijkstra(gra: graph)
```

```cpp
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void MetalFunc(constant int *graph        [[ buffer(0) ]],
                      constant int *result   [[ buffer(1) ]],
                      uint   index [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]
{


    const int size = sizeof(*graph);
    int result[size][size];

    for(int k = 0; k<size; k++){
        result[index][k]=graph[index][k]+graph[index][k]; //ERROR: Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861360/swift-bridging-2d-array-to-type-unsafepointerunsafemutablepointerdouble?

Comment: this isn't metal specific enough, not c++ and i somehow lack the ability to abstract what they are doing do my problem. I can see that they are trying something with buffers and 2D arrays, but that's it

Comment: The question I linked is not Metal specific, and talks about a problem very similar to yours (if not identical): calling a C function that needs a 2-D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the Swift implementation but your kernel function is wrong.

If you want to **write** to and **read** from the same buffer you should use `Device` address space attribute.

> The device address space name refers to buffer memory objects
> allocated from the device memory pool that are both readable and
> writeable.

```
device int *result /* write and read */
constant int *graph /* read only */
```

This is the correct implementation:

```
    #include <metal_stdlib>
    using namespace metal;
    
    kernel void MetalFunc(constant int *graph  [[ buffer(0) ]],
                          device int *result   [[ buffer(1) ]],
                          uint   index [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]
    {
    
         /* Point to an array (graph buffer) */
         constant int(*r)[6][6] = (constant int(*)[6][6])graph;
         /* Point to an array (result buffer) */
         device int(*w)[6][6] = (device int(*)[6][6])result;
         /* Read the first element */
         int i = (*r)[0][0];

         (*w)[0][0] = 777; /* Write to the first element */
         (*w)[5][5] = 999; /* Write to the last element */
    }
```

Comment: how do I read the result buffer in Swift? As far as I can see, my buffer is a 1d array, not 2d. I think it's size is wrong and reading it is also not implemented correctly.